# JMockit: Singleton class, Order of test

Tags: java, junit, singleton, private-members, jmockit

I have a Singleton class to test:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance;

    private List<String> list;

    private Singleton() {

    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                instance = new Singleton();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean methodOne() {
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list = SomeClass.fillListOne();
        }
        return SomeClass.verifyList(list);
    }

    public boolean methodTwo() {
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list = SomeClass.fillListTwo();
        }
        return SomeClass.verifyList(list);
    }
}
```

With the following test class:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class SingletonTest {
    @Test
    public void testOne(final @Mocked SomeClass someClass) {
        Singleton.getInstance().methodOne();
        new Verifications() {
            {
                SomeClass.fillListOne();
            }
        };

    }

    @Test
    public void testTwo(final @Mocked SomeClass someClass) {
        Singleton.getInstance().methodTwo();
        new Verifications() {
            {
                SomeClass.fillListTwo();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If I execute only "testOne" or only "testTwo", the tests pass. If I execute all tests, it passes only the first method executed. How can I set "list" attribute to null, for instance in a @Before method? How to use Deencapsulation with Singleton or private member without setters?

Comment: FYI: that getInstance method is incredibly unsafe. You cannot synchronize inside of a null check and expect it to be safe. Thread A comes in and checks to see if instance is null, it isn't so it continues. Context switch, Thread B comes in to check if instance is null, it still isn't so it continues. Thread B obtains the lock, and initializes some Object, assigns it to instance (which is guaranteed to be assigned and initialized per the requirements of synchronized), and releases the lock. Context switch, Thread A now obtains the lock and does the same, overwriting instance from ThreadB.

Comment: recommended reading for newbie Java concurrency developers: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html (you made the very first mistake detailed here)

Comment: Clarification: "(which is guaranteed to be assigned and initialized per the requirements of synchronized)", means that by the time the lock is released, the object is guaranteed to be assigned and initialized. The order of which that happens inside of the synchronized block is non-deterministic, per the JMM. To further clarify, your example does fall prey to that, but also falls prey to my initial example (which is irrelevant of the the JMM, but knowing how the JMM handles this will alleviate your 'solution' to that problem, which the link I posted details why it won't work).

Comment: Thanks searchengine27, but the question wasn't about Singleton and synchronization. As I wrote in an older comment, I cannot edit original class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That class is not particularly susceptible to testing. I'd urge you to rewrite it if you have the option to. (Testing with mocked static method calls is a maintenance nightmare, and I also have a general dislike of all things singleton-y -- they seem to be used everywhere whether they should be or not).

Regardless, [the documentation suggests](http://jmockit.github.io/api1x/mockit/Deencapsulation.html#setField-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) you could do something like this (I also added an extra field for readability, though you don't have to):

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class SingletonTest {
    private Singleton instance;

    @Before
    public void initialise() {
        Deencapsulation.setField(Singleton.class, "instance", null);
        instance = Singleton.getInstance();
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne(final @Mocked SomeClass someClass) {
        instance.methodOne();
        new Verifications() {
            {
                SomeClass.fillListOne();
            }
        };
    }
    // ...other tests...
}
```

Comment: THANKS! The class that I wrote is a simplification of a more complicated class that I can not edit. I don't want to set null the instance, only the list. So I edit your initialise method:instance = Singleton.getInstance(); Deencapsulation.setField(instance, "list", null);

Comment: @borras Yep, been there, that's where nasty reflection stuff like the above becomes useful. As for the resetting the `list` -- your test will be more robust if you reset the whole `instance`, rather than just part of it (I assume running resources aren't an issue)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a problem with the existing answer: even when the methods of SomeClass are ***not*** called, the test passes. That defeats the purpose of the test: it should pass *if and only if* methods SomeClass.fillListOne() and SomeClass.fillListTwo() are called.

Here's the way to verify the calls with JMockit, using NonStrictExpectations on the dependency SomeClass to return null. I've tested it using the same example provided in the question, it fails when the calls are not made and passes when they are:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class SingletonTest {
    // capturing ensures Jmockit will mock all SomeClass instances.
    @Capturing
    private SomeClass someClass;

    @Before
    public void prepareTests() {
        new NonStrictExpectations() {{
            SomeClass.fillListOne(); result = null;
            SomeClass.fillListTwo(); result = null;
        }};
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        Singleton.getInstance().methodOne();
        new Verifications() {{
            SomeClass.fillListOne();
        }};
    }

    @Test
    public void testTwo() {
        Singleton.getInstance().methodTwo();
        new Verifications() {{
            SomeClass.fillListTwo();
        }};
    }
}
```